# Can I get chickenpox from meeting someone who lives with someone else with chickenpox?

Tags: disease-transmission, chickenpox

Title mostly says it all. I've never had chickenpox. I was given chickenpox vaccine shots twice, once as an infant, and once at around 12-13 years old. I am now 23 years old. Am I safe? Or should I not meet this person until the other person (a 5 year old child, being cared for NOT by the person I might meet) has recovered? I'm not pregnant or otherwise in a category that should NOT risk chickenpox even a tiny bit, but obviously I'd rather avoid getting it.

I am asking both, the contagiousness of a housemate of a sick person, and whether my vaccinations are still effective (I understand it can't be 100% guaranteed).

Comment: Are you asking whether TWO vaccinations (everyone I know has one at the most) actually protect you, or about the contagiousness of a housemate of a sick person? Also, is the sick person an adult, who is caring for themselves, or a child, being cared for by the person you might meet? Finally, are you pregnant or otherwise in a category that should NOT risk chickenpox even a tiny bit?

Comment: Also, the answer to this question: http://health.stackexchange.com/q/3536/400 explains how the infection is spread.